# Django Pytest image upload image unit test

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I'm using Django 3.2.6, django-pytest, and factory boy to run automated tests.

This is the function I use to make a test image:

```
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile


def test_image(name='test.jpg', size=(250,250)):
    img = Image.new('RGB', size)
    content = img.tobytes()

    # return Django file for testing in forms and serializers
    return SimpleUploadedFile(name, content=content, content_type='image/jpeg')
```

This is the view being tested:

```
class PhotoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Photo
    form_class = PhotoForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'photos/create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_category = form.cleaned_data['new_category']
        if new_category:
            category = Category.objects.create(name=new_category)
            form.instance.category = category
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the test class:

```
class TestPhotoCreateView:
    url = reverse('photos:create')

    def test_photo_create_view_authenticated_user_can_access(self, client, user):
        client.force_login(user)
        response = client.get(self.url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
    
    def test_photo_create_view_unauthenticated_user_cannot_access(self, client):
        response = client.get(self.url)
        assert response.status_code == 302

    def test_photo_create_view_form_valid_existing_category(self, client, user):
        client.force_login(user)

        for _ in range(3):
            CategoryFactory()
        
        category = CategoryFactory()
        image = test_image()

        form_data = {
            'category': category.pk, 
            'new_category': '', 
            'description': 'hello world', 
            'image': image,
        }
        response = client.post(self.url, form_data)
        print(response.content)
        photo = Photo.objects.get(description=form_data['description'])
        assert photo.category == form_data['category']
```

All of the tests pass except for `test_photo_create_view_form_valid_existing_category`.
i ran `pytest --capture=tee-sys` and this error was in the image field:

`<p id="error_1_id_image" class="invalid-feedback"><strong>Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.</strong></p>`

How do I get the upload to pass the tests?

All of the code for this project is here: https://github.com/leigh-data/photo_gallery

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me for a Django unittest for an ImageField:

```
    def test_update_graphic(
     ...
 ):
     size = (800, 600)
     storage = BytesIO()
     img = Image.new("RGB", size)
     img.save(storage, "JPEG")
     storage.seek(0)
     file = SimpleUploadedFile(
         name="test_image.jpg", content=storage.getvalue(), content_type="image/jpeg"
     )
     ....
     data = {}
     data[parameter] = file

     ....post(url, data=data, format="multipart")
```